How can I add 'Where' condition and also 'OR' condition to the Queryable Variable inside the loop
I am trying to give 'OR' condition a IQueryable variable. Inside a loop first time it should be updated with Where condition, Then it should be updated with 'OR' along with the above Where condition. I am trying to Add it dynamically for each Iteration of the loop. Please can you give me help with a code how to bring OR condition to the existing  Result with Where
For Example
Select * from Employee Where EmployeeName = 'None' OR EmployeeName='John' OR EmployeeName='Lucy'

Here is the code in C#
var result = DbContext.EmployeeSearches.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted);

for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++)
{
    if (x == 0)
    {
        if (fd.Value.ToString() == "None")
        {
            result = result.Where(e => e.EmployeeName == null || e.EmployeeName == "None");
        }
        else
        {
            result = result.Where(e => e.EmployeeName == filter.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
    if (x > 0)
    {
        // I have to Add OR condition for another Employee Name. In First Iteration it 
        //should be filter with Where then second Iteration it should be applied 
        // 'OR'condition with result 
    }
}


Try: Include.

What is it you're trying to do here as it looks like you're trying to add a search for multiple employee names. Where do the names come from, are they in a variable for example?

You can't do that with .Where. Every Where call is automatically an "AND" statement. If you want to add multiple or instructions you must do it within ONE single .Where call, not in multiple. This is kinda complicated to do dynamically, because you must dynamically create an expression for every condition and pass that expression to .Where.

A few rough examples of Expression Trees can be seen in Dixin's Blog. Alternatively, fall back to System.Linq.Dynamic aka Dynamic Linq

Do you have any sample code on the basis of my question , it would be very appreciated
